# jQuery slideToggle parent and children

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
<li class="page_item "><a href="javascript:">A</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item "><a href="">B</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="page_item "><a href="">C</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

$('.page_item').click(function(){

    $('ul.children').slideToggle();
 });
ul.children{
  display: none;
}
```

[online sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kHLuR/)

How can I make like that, when I click A section, just to open A section's children when I click B, just show B's. not open the whole sections opened.
Thanks

Comment: As an aside, you should try putting in a `.stop()` before the `.slideUp()` so that it doesn't queue up a bunch of animations if you click multiple times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scope the slide toggle to the current element, using `this`:

```
$('.page_item').click(function(){
  var that = this;
  $('.page_item').each(function(){
   if(that == this)return true;//continue
   $('.children:not(:hidden)',this).slideToggle();
  });
  $('ul.children',this).slideToggle();
});
```

Edited to close other shown list. **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kHLuR/1/)**

Comment: Thank you, but if I opened Section A, and click Section B, Section A is still opened

Comment: how do I event.preventDefault(); on just the first level, the top menu? thanks

Comment: @olo - pass `event` into the function for the event, and then use `event.stopPropagation();`. Here is a demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/kHLuR/2/

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('.page_item').click(function(){
    $('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();

    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, how to prevent multi sections opened, just need one

Comment: I've edited my answer, it now closes the others before showing the one you want to open.